# How to accessibly make a fill-in-the-blank?

Tags: html, accessibility

In HTML, I would like to have something like this:

> `<p>A man, a ____, a canal, panama.</p>`

I do not want the underline/underscores to actually be an actual text input box. What would be a good way to mark this up in HTML such that it would be accessible to say, a screen reader? If it is possible to convey that the underline is four characters long, all the better.

---

Maybe my example is too far from my actual use case. Instead, imagine a simple math lesson in HTML, and something like this is visible:

> 2 + ___ = 5

There is no interactivity---no way for the reader to actually fill in 3 in an input field. It is only meant as an exercise to the reader and maybe somewhere else they could look up the answer. If I only use underscores or CSS underlining, there is no cue to a screen reader user that there is a blank there. They hear "two plus equals five".

Comment: Possible duplicate of [how to change input text box style to line?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3131072/how-to-change-input-text-box-style-to-line)

Comment: @Dorvalla That question is about styling an input field in a form. (Or do I misunderstand?) I don't want an actual input field, and I do not want a screen reader user to think they are expected to enter any text.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Depending on the "verbosity" setting of the screen reader, some symbols might be ignored.  For example, commas, periods, and parentheses are often not announced literally.  Underscores are often ignored too.  However, the user can change their screen reader settings to hear them.  But in your case, it'd be nice to hear the full expression without having to change the settings.

You can give alternate text to an element by using the [`aria-label`](https://www.w3.org/TR/wai-aria/#aria-label) attribute.  However, the `aria-label` is not always announced if it's used on a non-semantic element.  See "[2.10 Practical Support: aria-label, aria-labelledby and aria-describedby](https://www.w3.org/TR/using-aria/#label-support)", specifically, the third last bullet point about <div> and <span>.

In order for the `aria-label` to be honored, the element must have a semantic [`role`](https://www.w3.org/TR/wai-aria-1.1/#role_definitions).

For example, if you had:

```
<p>2 + ___ = 5</p>
```

the underscores would be ignored.  With NVDA on firefox, I hear "two plus equals five".  To fix that, I can give the "____" an `aria-label`.

```
<p>2 + <span aria-label="4 underscores">___</span> = 5</p>
```

However, because of the aforementioned issue that <span> elements don't have any semantic meaning, and thus the `aria-label` is ignored, you need to come up with a `role` for the <span>.

If you are truly showing math expressions, the following works with NVDA on firefox and VoiceOver on iOS:

```
<p>2 + <span role="math" aria-label="4 underscores">___</span> = 5</p>
```

I hear "two plus four underscores equals 5".

I'm not sure "math" is really the correct role here, but it does get you want you want with my limited testing.  You may want to look at the other [roles](https://www.w3.org/TR/wai-aria-1.1/#role_definitions) available.

Comment: Thank you for a very helpful explanation.

Comment: I don't think it matters _how many_ underscores there are. What is really being conveyed is that there is a deliberately empty space, where the answer would have been. In algebra this would be a "variable", but a maths term might not be what's needed here; something more plain-english would be better. How about `aria-label="blank"`, so it reads "2 plus blank equals 5".  I am of course taking my inspiration from the Blankety Blank TV game show. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Blankety_Blank

Comment: I don’t think the question was so much about **what** the label should be but rather how to code it so it reads well. Whether you have “4 underscores” or “blank” or whatever. The key seems to be to have an `aria-label` and a `role` so that the label is read.